# Simple method to remove files from a listbox - LOTUS 7

Tags: listbox, lotus-notes, attachment, items

So I have a button that displays a listbox that I've created. This listbox has some attachments, it is populated with some items ( the attachments ). Also, I created another button that I want to remove the items that I will select from the listbox. Is there any simple method/formula for doing this?

Comment: Please, be more specific, add code samples. And btw, by "listbox" you mean "@Prompt"?

Comment: By wanting to remove attachment items from the list, is the underlying purpose to remove file attachments from the document ? "Answerers" are asking for more info because this impacts the type of response given. Either you just want to edit a field, or modify the attached files to a document.

Answer (score 2):

Please try to explain a litte bit more clearly what you are trying to do.
I assume that by "listbox" you mean a field of type listbox. That kind of field can not contain attachments, just text values. Do you mean that the listbox contains the name of one or more attachments?

You talk about "a button that displays the listbox". Is that relevant to the problem?

How is the listbox created and populated? I assume from another, field, containing the names of the attachments?

I used some assumptions (you really need to explain your problems in more detail), and this is how I solved it:

---

Field 'ListData': Text field, hidden. Contains the values you want to display (e.g. names of attachments), separated by semicolon.

Field 'ListBox': Listbox field, allow multiple values, refresh choices on document refresh, use formula for choices: 
@Explode(ListData;";")

Button "Delete Selected":

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
    Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
    Dim selected As Variant
    Dim listdata As Variant
    Dim files List As String
    Dim newlistdata As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Set uidoc = ws.CurrentDocument
    '*** Read the field values and split into arrays
    listdata = Split( uidoc.FieldGetText("ListData"), ";" )
    selected = Split( uidoc.FieldGetText("ListBox"), ";" )
    '*** Convert listdata array into a Lotusscript list
    Forall file In listdata
        files(file) = file
    End Forall
    '*** Loop through the array of selected values
    For i = 0 To Ubound(selected)
        '*** Check if the currently processed value is in the files list
        If Iselement(files(selected(i))) Then
            Erase files(selected(i))    ' Remove/erase from the list
            '*** Add code here to remove attachments from document
            '*** if that is what you actually want to do.
            '*** Use notesEmbeddedObject.Remove method for that.
        End If  
    Next
    '*** Now we have the files list with the selected items removed.
    '*** Loop though the list and build a string of remaining values
    Forall ff In files
        newlistdata = newlistdata + ff + ";"    
    End Forall
    '*** Write the new string of remaining attachments back to the listdata field
    Call uidoc.FieldSetText("ListData", newlistdata)
    Call uidoc.Refresh
End Sub
```

You just need to think through the problem and figure out what you really want to do, then break it down to smaller steps, solve each one of those, etc. Lotusscript is not different from other languages in that way,

Note: The code may look complicated and is longer than it has to be, as I added plenty of comments so you (hopefully) can understand what is being done...

Answer (score 0):

1) Use hidden multivalue field for options in listbox. Its value will be computed based on default values (@Attachment or another field value) and will remove all values mentioned in another hidden field "removed" (@Replace).

2) "Removed" field will be populated by your Remove button like

```
FIELD removed := @Trim(@Unique(removed:listbox));@All
```

"listbox" contains values currently selected in listbox.

3) I recommend to provide some feedback of removed values and ability to undo/reset.